# My mobile application does not work when generated the release APK, but work perfectly on debug APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Release APK version doesn't send Firebase authentication code while the Debug APK works well.

It send the code, but the release don't work at all.

Please, I need some help.

Comment: have you used Proguard rule for gradel?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Does it crash? Or only some features don't work?

Comment: where is the code? What have you done so far to solve it?

Comment: please add your `build.gradle` and the `error log`.

Comment: when i meant it does not works means i used firebase authentication for the signing up once once it registered it sends authentication code to each mobile phone but these work well on my phone but does not work when is on google play store ..when i generated the release sha1 i added it to the firebase project but however once i upload it to the play store it wont send verification code again... or do i added the sha-1 key wrong

Answer (score 1):

in the firebase console, add release key.

1)Select your project in Firebase.
2) Inside your project, click on settings Icon-> Project Settings-> Add FingerPrint 
3) Add Release key( Sha1 ) and save.
4) download the JSON file by clicking on google-services.json.
5) Add this json file in the app folder.
6) Rebuild the the Android Project
7) Install the updated app and test.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you build.gradle for the minify -

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
               'proguard-rules.pro'
    }}
```

if you have this enabled then you have to use proguard to keep classes and interfaces which might be removed because of minify.

See here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html